# Get clicked object value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to rewrite a live search feature using AngularJS, but can't find how I can grab the currently clicked item in the list. See below:

```
<div id="searchResults" ng-show="speaker.list.length > 0">
  <ul ng-repeat="person in speaker.list">
    <li ng-click="speaker.updateFields()">{{person.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my `speaker.updateFields()` method, how do I reference `person.name`? Is there a different way this should be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it in!

```
<li ng-click="speaker.updateFields(person.name)">{{person.name}}</li>
```

And the JS

```
$scope.updateField = function(name) {
    //console.log(name)
}
```

Comment: Doh! So simple. LOL. Should have been obvious. Geez. :)

Comment: It's always the obvious ones that cause the most trouble

Answer (score 0):

When you use ng-repeat each item is assigned an index value as well.

```
<div ng-repeat='person in persons'>
    {{person.$index}}
</div>
```